# Log4j logs rolling in wrong files(Prior to current day, skipping week ends)

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I am using log4j-1.2.16.jar or my project
Here is my `log4j.properties`

```
# The default root appender - used to log service calls to console
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, LOGGER1, LOGGER2
#LOGGER1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender which outputs to System.out.
log4j.appender.LOGGER1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGGER1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGGER1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.LOGGER1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p [%X{USER_EMAIL}] %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.LOGGER1.File=D:/DevLogs/logger1.log
log4j.appender.LOGGER1.Threshold = ERROR

# An extra category to a log API Calls to a file
log4j.appender.LOGGER2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGGER2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.LOGGER2.File=D:/DevLogs/logger2.log
log4j.appender.LOGGER2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGGER2.layout.ConversionPattern= [%d] %p [%X{USER_EMAIL}] %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.LOGGER2.Threshold = INFO
```

Previously, I had two tomcat servers for two different applications which contains two `log4j.properties` and logs created properly. Now I we have only one tomcat server and we merged those two application wars in single war. But there are several services depending on this application, we need to give backward compatibility for one release. So we have only one war file on tomcat but by changing configuration in `server.xml` we use to create two different context. Here is snippet from my `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8445" server="Not Available"  maxThreads="1500"/>
<Connector port="8280" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8445" server="Not Available"  maxThreads="1500"/>

<Context docBase="application.war" path="/firstApplication" reloadable="true" />
<Context docBase="application.war" path="/secondApplication" reloadable="true" />
```

Application is running fine. But my logs rolling in wrong files. For example, today is 2nd July, so till afternoon, logs works fine, but after that 2nd July logs start printing in prior to one day i.e. 1st July file. And another complex is this process skip weekend. Means for Saturday and Sunday, logs are fine but Monday's, logs move in Friday's log file.
I am totally blank, what's going wrong. Same configuration file works for two different servers but having issue with two logic al context. If any one have any suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is starting to sound like you're having two applications (contexts) in the container with the same log configuration - they're going to step on each other - almost guaranteed.

That may explain why your log rolling behavior is so erratic.

There is no simple/easy fix for this. You can investigate external rolling mechanisms like logrotate (if you're hosting on a unix system) as an option.

You might be able to utilize a combination of logback+slf4j to accomplish a way around this though.  Slf4j provides a plug for plug re-route library to subvert log4j based logging.  I have used this to replace log4j with logback+slf4j in an application and managed to make sure that dependent libraries (which were written against log4j) still operate properly.

Additionally, you may be able to utilize logback's [context selector](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html#contextSelectors) to determine what/when log files are rotated.

Without providing separate application deployments, your log4j configuration is going to conflict between the two apps and result in the behavior you are seeing.

**EDIT** Based on questions/commentary by OP, the following should provide a way to accomplish the context based selection.

With regard to your situation, that it is one application deployed under two contexts, try doing the following from the server.xml.  It will provide an Environment entry into the JNDI tree for the deployed context.

```
<Context docBase="application.war" path="/firstApplication" reloadable="true">
    <Environment name="logback/context-name" value="firstApplication" type="java.lang.String" />
</Context>
<Context docBase="application.war" path="/secondApplication" reloadable="true">
    <Environment name="logback/context-name" value="secondApplication" type="java.lang.String" />
</Context>
```

At this point, you should be able follow the documentation based on the context selector.

Comment: I can't go with Context selector as I have only one war file which is getting extracted while server start-up and create folders with the context names configured in `server.xml`. This configuration will be there on Production only for next 1 month so it's not feasible to make too many changes. Is there any configuration changes to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which tomcat version are you running?

Comment: `Apache Tomcat/7.0.54`

Comment: I'll have an edit for you in 30 that will get you around that issue

Comment: OK. I'll wait for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I used log4j and don't want to change it just for one month. Let me check with logback and sure I will let you know about same.